# Running a php cli script and I'm getting Argument list too long

Tags: command-line-interface, php

I did encounter this error `bash: ...: Argument list too long` 
but I reduced the number of arguments and I have this error: `exec: 90: /usr/bin/php: Argument list too long`. how can I increase the argument list in PHP?

Comment: How many arguments do you think you have? What OS are you on (assume unix cos you mention bash)? Would xargs help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't PHP causing that error it's bash. It only allows so many arguments. There are ways around it however. Most likely the script is doing something like if you execute "md5sum *" in a directory with 5,000 files, you'll get the same error; even though the only argument you passed is *. 5,000 filenames are passed.

Check here:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060

Good luck!